# Use ESD5500E with flywheel generator

Tags: sensor, motor-controller, speed

I would like to use the motor speed controller ESD5500E. Manual [here](http://www.governors-america.com/documents/PIB1002E_ESD5500E.pdf).

The stationary engine which should be controled is equiped with a single phase flywheel generator which I have connected to a charging rectifier. The engine RPM range is between 600 RPM and 2200 RPM. Voltage is delivered from the flywheel generator between 1V and 18V AC.

Can I use the AC signal of the flywheel generator instead the speed control sensor?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use the AC signal of the flywheel generator instead the speed control sensor?

It is very unlikely that this will work. The generator will give one or two AC cycles per revolution depending on the number of poles on the alternator. The controller is designed to monitor the speed using a magnetic pickup reading a gear ring so it may have in the order of 100 teeth. Having  more teeth means shorter time between pulses. The higher the feedback frequency the better the resolution and response time for speed control.